# What is the proper way to include a python class from another visual studio project?

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

In visual studio 2013, I made up a python solution with a source code project *PythonApplication1* and a unit test project named *PythonApplication.UnitTests*. This is the folder structure:

[image]

In the unit test project, I added a search path to the *PythonApplication1*-Project. But when I run unit tests, the following error occurs:

*...PathToSolution\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.UnitTests\Test_MyOwnClass.py", line 2, in  from MyOwnClass import MyOwnClass ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyOwnClass'*

I also tried to add the path to my PythonSettings file, but got the same result out of it. Here is the content of PythonSettings.json:

```
{
"TestFramework": "unittest",
"UnitTestRootDirectory": "PythonApplication1.UnitTests",
"UnitTestPattern": "Test_*.py",
"SearchPaths": [ "..\PythonApplication1" ]
}
```

Content of MyOwnClass.py:

```
class MyOwnClass:
    attribute1 = 0
```

Content of Test_MyOwnClass.py:

```
import unittest
from MyOwnClass import MyOwnClass

class Test_test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        myOwn = MyOwnClass()
        self.assertEqual( 0, myOwn.attribute1 )
```

What Did I miss when integrating `MyOwnClass` to my unit test project?